# How do I solve - column libman_llrguides.id does not exist

Tags: sql, django

I have a model in my django app as shown below...

```
class LLRGuides(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField(default='Type the description of the guide here')
```

I manually created the table in my databse thro' the pg_admin, manually added the columns.
The problem comes in when I try to create an instance of the model, it complains of id column not being present.

```
null value in column "id" of relation "libman_llrguides" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (d, d, Type the description of the guide here, null).
```

This is the sql that created the id field in the pg_Admin

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.libman_llrguides
    ADD COLUMN id integer NOT NULL;
```

Comment: No, this does not complain about the column not being present. It complains that the database does not automatically assigns a value for `id`, and thus hence raises an error.

Comment: Then a solution wouldbe?? @WillemVanOnsem